# Как правильно анимировать удаление элемента с помощью framer-motion?

Tags: reactjs

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку удаления анимируются все элементы, но если убрать `exitBeforeEnter`, то все работает нормально. Убирать его не вариант, т.к в таком случае в проекте пропадает плавная смена элементов при смене пункта меню.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { name: "1 item" },
    { name: "2 item" },
    { name: "3 item" },
    { name: "4 item" },
    { name: "5 item" },
    { name: "6 item" }
  ]);
  const deleteItem = (item) => {
    setItems(items.filter((el) => item !== el));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <AnimatePresence initial={false} exitBeforeEnter>
        {items.map((el, id) => (
          <motion.div
            key={id}
            style={{
              background: "#eee",
              width: "200px",
              margin: "10px",
              padding: "10px"
            }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 1 }}
          >
            {el.name}

            <strong
              onClick={() => deleteItem(el)}
              style={{ float: "right", marginRight: "10px" }}
            >
              X
            </strong>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mclaren-nfi0g?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции удаления нужно переводить `exitBeforeEnter` в `false`, в таком случае все адекватно работает